# Flexbox + overflow:hiddden works only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am having problem with contents of my left sidebar not respecting `overflow:hidden` anywhere other than Chrome browser.
In Firefox, IE and Edge sidebar is extended instead of being limited to 300 pixels of `.container` div. Does anyone know how to fix this behavior?

https://jsfiddle.net/o1uu1d0L/2/

Comment: Your example is wrong - you have a `.buttons-container` which contains the `overflow: hidden`, but that class is nowhere in use in the example. If you put `overflow: hidden` on the `.container`-class, it works as intended, I think?

Comment: the fiddle is not clear when I look it after reading the question... could you please check it?

Comment: Sorry, I left some classes that were not supposed to be there. `overflow:hidden` I had problem with is declared in `style` attribute of `div`. Both answers from @mohsen-newtoa and @patryk-Łucka fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
.flex-fill {
    display:flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

to

```
.flex-fill {
    display:flex;
    min-height: 0;
    flex:1 1 0%;
}
```

I think there are two reasons why this problem occurs:

The first problem is that IE does not accept unitless `flex-basis`. That's why you have to use `flex: 1 1 0%` or `flex: 1 1 0px` but not `flex: 1 1 0`. And `flex: 1 1 auto` did not work in this case as well.

The second problem is different interpretation of `display: flex` in Chrome and Firefox. Firefox, by default, sets `min-height: auto; min-width: auto;` on `display: flex` elements and Chrome sets it as `min-height: 0; min-width: 0`. And what you need is second option.

I'm not sure if that simple change will solve all your problems (but it looked ok when i tested it on IE and Firefox). If not, please think about what I  wrote and make similar changes in other classes. I hope it will help!

Comment: Here it is explained in more details, maybe it will help: https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/

Comment: Thank you for great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

your codes with a few changes :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-col flex-fill">
        <div class="flex-row flex-fill">
            <div class="flex-col flex-50 dragscroll default-box" style="margin-right:5px;">
                <div class="button selected">1</div>
                <div class="button">2</div>
                <div class="button selected">3</div>
                <div class="button">4</div>
                <div class="button">5</div>
                <div class="button selected">6</div>
                <div class="button selected">7</div>
                <div class="button">8</div>
                <div class="button">9</div>
                <div class="button">10</div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-fill default-box">
                center
            </div>

            <div class="flex-250 default-box" style="margin-left:5px;">
                side
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="default-box flex-50" style="margin-top:5px;">
            bottom
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column;
    background:lightblue;
}

.buttons-container {
    min-height:1px;
    height:100%;
    flex:0 1 50px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background:#FFF;
    margin-right:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column;
}

.flex-col {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.flex-row {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.flex-fill {
    display:flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

.flex-50 {
    display:flex;
    flex:0 0 50px;
}

.flex-250 {
    display:flex;
    flex:0 0 250px;
}

.default-box {
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.plot-area {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    flex:1 1 auto;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.button {
    background:#cfeceb;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#56b6b2;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:26px;
    flex:1 1 auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    min-height:50px;
}

.button.selected {
    background:#56b6b2;
    color:#FFF;
}

.button:last-child {
    margin:0 !important;
}
```